# 18% gray paint manufacturers

Tags: color-management, white-balance, studio, gray-card

I want this to kind of be a "mega thread" of paint.

So, here is the scenario: I have a room that I want to use as a studio. Since this room will only be used for photography, I want to have it painted in some standard colors. I'd like one wall 100% black, two walls 100% white, and one wall 18% gray.

Now, the idea is that I can rely on these walls instead of having a gray card. Yes, having a gray card would be easier and cheaper, but that is not the point of this question.

Can you give me a manufacturer and their color codes to create those colors of paint?

Edit:
Original had 50% gray and not the correct 18%

Answer (score 6):

The standard gray card is 18% gray. Take a sample gray card with you to the paint store and have them custom mix. The reflection readings are:
0.75 red  0.75 green 0.75 blue 0.75 via the yellow visual filter. These values are the reflection densities of the gray card.

Comment: You're 100% right. I'm going to change the title.